# Django Admin - change user type (is_staff = T/F) based on group assignment

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I have a django app with 3 types of user, super_user, admin, user. From django-admin panel I am assigning a user to Admin group. Admin group is a group with allowed permission. So when I am assigning a user I am changing their is_staff to True in GroupAdminForm. Problem is when I remove a user from the group I can not change those users is_staff to false. Here's my GroupAdminForm

Also I see that save_m2m is being called 2 times, but I am calling it once. what is the flow of saving here ?

```py
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = []

    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset=User.objects.all(),
         required=False,
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users', False)
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        old_users = None
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.user_set.all()
            old_users = self.instance.user_set.all()

    def save_m2m(self):
        print(f'Users = ', self.instance.user_set.all())
        print(f'M2M Called - {self.test}')
        self.instance.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data['users'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save()
        all_users = self.instance.user_set.all()
        print('Save Called')

        self.save_m2m()

        users = self.cleaned_data['users']
        if instance.name == 'Admin':
            for user in users:
                user.is_staff = True
                user.save()


        return instance
```

Comment: These three user types/levels are already implemented on the built-in User model with boolean fields (is_superuser and is_staff) why do you need or want to use Groups for this?

Comment: I need to assign different permissions to my admin type user and I want to call this user admin not staff. I could not rename is_staff to say is_admin and keep same functionality. SuperUser or User type works fine with built in functionality @IainShelvington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> save_m2m is being called 2 times

**save()** method accepts an optional **commit** keyword argument, which accepts either `True` or `False` (default is **True**). If you call **save()** with `commit=True`, your case here:

```
instance = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save()
```

Django will call **save_m2m()** automatically. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)
To prevent that use `commit=False`

```
 instance = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

> Problem is when I remove a user from the group I can not change those users is_staff to false

Use [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) signal to update the `is_staff` attribute

Comment: hi thanks for this. But m2m_changed signals is used with models but in my case I am using custom user and group, so I am not sure how I will use the throufh relation.